# Exclude folder from next JS build

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I have a bulky folder full of backend & config code located in `/src/config` inside my Next JS app.

I don't need to ship any of this code to the client when building. Is there a best practice for excluding this folder from building in Next JS? Thanks

Comment: It shouldn't be bundled with your client side code if you never use it on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to ignore that folder from build process, you can use a work-around with [ignore-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ignore-loader).

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rules?.push({
      test: /route-to-ignore/,
      loader: "ignore-loader",
    });
    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

In case you want it only on server side. Just make sure that you don't import anything from these files into your client side code, e.g., pages, components, hooks, etc.